# How to find an average in SQL, while using the average to find the difference between the initial data values and the average

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm writing a query to get a specific output.

I've tried using the `avg` command. I am unable to figure out how to use the output to find the difference between the total values and the average.

```
select ProductID,ProductDescription,StandardPrice
from PRODUCT_TBL

select AVG(StandardPrice) as AveragePrice
from PRODUCT_TBL
```

I expected the output to be the average of all the values, which I got. It's just the find the difference between the initial values and the average.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to find the difference between a given row's standard price and the table's average, you may try using `AVG` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT
    ProductID,
    ProductDescription,
    StandardPrice,
    AVG(StandardPrice) OVER () AS AvgStandardPrice,
    StandardPrice - AVG(StandardPrice) OVER () AS Difference
FROM PRODUCT_TBL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an option of using a subquery to get the Average

```
SELECT
    ProductID,
    ProductDescription,
    StandardPrice,
    StandardPrice - (SELECT AVG(StandardPrice) FROM PRODUCT_TBL) AS Difference
FROM PRODUCT_TBL;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve the desired result set in two different ways, given below.

1. Using Inner Query

   ```
   SELECT ID, NAME, PRICE, 
   (SELECT AVG(PRICE) FROM #A ) AS AVGSTANDARDPRICE, 
   (PRICE - ( SELECT AVG(PRICE) FROM #A )) AS DIFFRENCE 
   FROM #A
   ```

2.Using Predefined Calculated Average Price.

```
 DECLARE @AVGPRICE MONEY
 SET @AVGPRICE = ( SELECT AVG(ISNULL(PRICE,0)) FROM #A )    
 SELECT ID,
 NAME,
 PRICE,
 @AVGPRICE AS AVGSTANDARDPRICE,    
 (PRICE - @AVGPRICE ) AS DIFFRENCE
 FROM #A
```